# Physical meaning of the form factors $F_1(q^2)$ and $F_2(q^2)$ for $q^2\neq 0$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment

The charge form factor $F_1(q^2)$ and the anomalous magnetic moment form factor $F_2(q^2)$ have clear interpretations at the value $q^2=0$ i.e. $F_1(0)$ is equal to the charge of the electron and $F_2(0)$ is equal to $(g_e-2)/2$. Is there a physical interpretation for $F_1(q^2)$ and $F_2(q^2)$ when $q^2\neq 0$?

Comment: Does $F_2(q^2)$ not simply provide the correction to the g-factor when measured at the energy scale of $q^2$ (the special case of $F_2(0)$ being the correction in the non-relativistic limit)?

Comment: How did you define these form factors that their meaning is not evident to you? (Supplying your definition is also necessary so that answerers know where to start their explanation)

Comment: @NiharKarve The magnetic moment is usually measured at the "magic momentum" $p=3\,\mathrm{GeV}$. Still, we compare the measurement to $F(0)$, not to $F(p^2)$. So I don't think your interpretation is quite correct.

Answer (score 2):

Very crudely, form factors away from the origin represent spatial distributions of charge or anomalous magnetic moment in the Rosenbluth formula, in Fourier space, so the leading (small nonzero) $q^2$ behavior specifies the long-distance extent of these distributions, the next moment shorter distance details, etc...
You might extend the intuition to virtual distribution clouds of anything induced by renormalization phenomena.

At the primitive and original level,  the idea is clear already in large-angle high-energy Mott scattering: The *1/r* point charge potential of the nucleus is modified by a charge distribution $\rho({\mathbf x})$ for the Born approximation,
$$
-\frac{Ze}{4\pi |{\mathbf x}|}\longrightarrow -\frac{1}{4\pi} \int \!d^3 {\mathbf x}'\frac{\rho({\mathbf x'})}{ |{\mathbf x}- {\mathbf x}'|} ~,
$$
so the factor multiplying the energy conservation $\delta$ is $-Ze F({\mathbf q})/|{\mathbf q}^2|$, where ${\mathbf q}={\mathbf p}'-{\mathbf p}$ :
$$
 F({\mathbf q})=\frac{1}{-Ze}\int d^3 {\mathbf x} ~\rho({\mathbf x}) e^{-i\mathbf {x\cdot q}} \\
=\frac{1}{-Ze}\int d^3 {\mathbf x} ~\rho({\mathbf x}) 
(1-i\mathbf {x\cdot q}- (\mathbf {x\cdot q})^2/2+...)
$$
as an expansion in small $\mathbf {q}$.

So, for instance, for a spherically symmetric charge distribution, the above integral reduces to
$$
1-\frac{\langle r^2\rangle}{6} |\mathbf {  q}|^2+ ..., \qquad  \hbox{where}\\
\langle r^2\rangle = {\int d^3 {\mathbf x} ~r^2\rho(r^2) \over \int d^3 {\mathbf x} ~\rho( r)} ,
$$
is the radius-squared of the proton charge distribution that Hofstadter measured to  glorious effect (NP 1961).

Higher moments will reveal  more detailed internal features, moving within, and of course lower ones, if not vanishing , as here, dipole distribution asymmetries. It is a Fourier shape-from-moments reconstruction problem. I understand nuclear physics thrives on such maps, if I recall the Jefferson Lab talks copious in the community.

[image]